# Server continues to look to old Update Site database

Tags: eclipse, osgi, xpages, xpages-extlib, update-site

I had (by mistake) a copy of an update site on one server. I had the correct copy on another server so I replicated it to the first server and deleted the original bad update site DB. I found the entry OSGI_HTTP_DYNAMIC_BUNDLES= in the Notes.ini that was pointing to the update DB that I deleted, so I changed it to the new database name, shut down the server and then restarted it. and I get the following error
08/05/2014 12:41:38 PM  HTTP JVM: NotesException: Invalid replica id (WFSUpDat.nsf)

where WFSUpDat.nsf is the old (wrong) update site. So Domino is storing this information somewhere else. Can someone give me a pointer as to where it is.

Also if I use the command line
tell http osgi ss com.ibm,xsp.extlib
I get a list of the installed extension library, I have the debug toolbar 4.01 installed in the update site what would the command line be to get the same thing to confirm the version of the toolbar?

Thanks

Comment: Interesting... did you try to remove the notes.ini entry completely, restarting the server and adding the new one afterwards?

Comment: No I have not, will give that a try.

Comment: I removed the entry from the Notes.ini completely, restarted the server, got the same message, looked at the Notes.ini and it had the line in it:
OSGI_HTTP_DYNAMIC_BUNDLES=WFSUpDat.nsf
so clearly the value is getting stored somewhere else and over-riding the Notes.ini
Next step is to search the Window Registry.

Comment: Check param document in Domino Directory first :-)

Comment: @Frantisek - not sure I understand what document is this?

Comment: Bill, it's the notes.ini section in a configuration document. Check names.nsf under Servers -> Configurations

Comment: One of the rules of stress free Domino admin is "you shall not edit the notes.ini" - following that rule leads to the use of configuration documents as Per pointed out

Comment: *Per - Thanks, old habits die hard!

Answer (score 0):

Make the change in the Server Configuration document in the Server Names.nsf, not directly in the Notes.ini
Should know better, but .......